# How to use browserify "require" in console?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, browserify

I installed `browserify` and `pinyin` package in my rails project by using `browserify-rails`.

https://github.com/hotoo/pinyin

```
var pinyin = require("pinyin");
console.log(pinyin("中心"));  // [ [ 'zhōng' ], [ 'xīn' ] ]
```

It works well. But I can't use the library from Google Chrome console.

```
> pinyin
VM362:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: pinyin is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM362:1
> var pinyin = require("pinyin");
VM364:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:15
```

I thought `pinyin` variable is already declared, but it's not.
And `require` function can't be called from console.

How can I use the library from REPL environment?

Answer (score 0):

To expose a required module for use outside of the bundle, you should use the [`--require`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) option:

```
browserify index.js --require pinyin > bundle.js
```

I'm unfamiliar with `browserify-rails`, so I'm not sure how it ought to be configured, but `--require` is the option you will need to specify.